# Is a relation, R, an Equivalence Relation of a Power Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Where $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $S = P(A)$ is the power set, for $a,b \in S$ define a relation $R: (a,b) \in R$ where $a$ and $b$ have the same number of elements.

Is $R$ an equivalence relation on $S$ and if so how many equivalence classes are there?

I've defined my $R$ as being $\{(\{1,2\},\{3,4\}),(\{1,2\},\{5,6\}),(\{1,2\},\{1,2\}),(\{3,4\},\{1,2\}),(\{3,4\},\{3,4\}),(\{3,4\},\{5,6\}),(\{5,6\},\{1,2\}),(\{5,6\},\{3,4\}),(\{5,6\},\{5,6\})\}$

because of the part of the question mentioning $a$ and $b$ have the same number of elements. Was that wrong to do?

Comment: "I've defined my $R$ as being..." There, you've already started making a mistake. You aren't defining $R$ - the problem defined $R$. The $R$ you've defined is very different from the $R$ that the problem defined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've recognised my problem there, and have since realised that if it is an equivalence relation of $A$, then it must also be of $P(A)$ since $A \in P(A)$. I'm now struggling though to prove how many equivalence classes there are.

Comment: No, that's not true. @Gareth. An equivalence relation on $A$ does not mean an equivalence relation on $P(A)$.

Comment: Oh... So would R not be an equivalence relation on S as @Jackswastedlife says below?

Comment: No, $R$ is defined precisely above as an equivalence relation on $S$ - it is a subset of the set of pairs of elements of $S$, not of pairs of elements of $A$. "For each $a,b\in S$, define ... $R$..." There is no relation defined on $A$.

Comment: I see that $R$ contains pairs of sets that are elements of $P(A)$ , I don't see how I can prove that those elements prove that it is an equivalence relation of $P(A)$. I can see now why there are 7 equivalence classes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $f:X\to Y$ is a function then the relation $R$ on $X$ defined by: $$uRv\iff f(u)=f(v)$$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

Equality $f(u)=f(u)$ guarantees reflexivity.

Implication $f(u)=f(v)\implies f(v)=f(u)$ guarantees symmetry.

Implication $f(u)=f(v)\wedge f(v)=f(w)\implies f(u)=f(w)$ guarantees transitivity.

It is always possible (and handsome) to let $f$ be surjective by restricting its codomain. Then equivalence classes are the fibres $f^{-1}(\{y\}):=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\}$ for $y\in Y$ and consequently the cardinality of $Y$ equals the number of equivalence classes.

You can apply this here on function $f:S\to\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ prescribed by:$$s\mapsto\text{number of elements of }s$$

This function is surjective and the cardinality of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $7$. So there are $7$ equivalence classes.

Comment: I understand what gives a relation equivalence. What are fibres? I think if I understand that then I'll understand why there are 7 equivalence classes.

Comment: @Gareth The answer defines *fibres* immediately after using the term.

Comment: @BrianO I don't understand it, honestly

Comment: @Gareth The identity immediately following defines the term. Never mind. Just ditch the term "fibre", and assume the sentence reads "... equivalence classes are the inverse images $f^{-1}(\{y\}):=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=y\}$ ...".

Comment: What I mean to say is that I don't understand the equation.

Comment: @BrianO An inverse function, $f^{-1}$ of a set containing $y$ is defined as a set of $x$s (which are elements of $X$) but only where the function's inverse of an element (in $X$) equals $y$. That is so confusing. Can I have an example?

Comment: @Gareth Yeah, so? Your qualification "but only when.." isn't correct: the inverse image is defined that way, period, whether $y$ is or is not in the range of $f$. If $y$ isn't in the range of $f$ then $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \emptyset$. [The rest of that sentence is garbled: "only where *the function's inverse of an element (in X) equals y*" — maybe you mean "image" not "inverse".] But anyway that's never the case here: $f$ is a surjection from $\mathcal{P}(A)$ onto $\{0, 1, \dotsc 6\}$.

Comment: @BrianO Okay, so, that shows that equivalence classes are the inverse images... Is finding the inverse image key to showing that there are 7 equivalence classes for the set $A$? Why a surjection, and not a bijection/injection?

Comment: I mentioned surjection just because of your concern that some of the ... fibres... might be empty. Equivalence classes are always NONempty. The point is, for any function $f$, $\{f^{-1}(\{y\})\mid y\in range(f)\}$ is a partition of $domain(f)$, the corresponding equivalence relation is $R$ as defined in the answer above. // But all of this is perhaps overgeneralizing. **How many equivalence classes are there for the relation in your question?** It should be obvious by now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that was wrong to do since you missed a lot of sets for example
$$
(\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\})\in R
$$

$R$ is indeed an equivalence relation (appeal to the definition) and any two members of an equivalence class have same number elements. There are $7$ possible cardinalities including $0$ and hence there are $7$ equivalence classes.

Comment: Oh of course, $a$ and $b$ are the same length there still. I see my error. Thank you.

Comment: You and @ThomasAndrews seem to have differing opinions on whether R is an equivalence relation of P(A)

Comment: $R$ is a subset of $P(A)^2$, wouldn't you agree? So $R$ is a relation on $S=P(A)$ as ThomasAndrews says, it's not a relation on $A$. A relation on $A$ would be a subset of $A^2$ and have elements like $(1,2)$ instead of elements like $(\{1,2\},\{2,3\})$.

Comment: @Jackswastedlife oh I see, okay. So we've established $R$ contains a whole bunch of sets, so many I couldn't write them all out...And those sets have elements of $P(A)$ in them... I still don't know how to show $R$ is an equivalence relation of $P(A)$ without writing out the entire thing.

Comment: If $\#$ denotes the number of elements you could do something like this. $\#(x)=\#(x)\implies(x,x)\in  R\;\forall x\in P(A)$. $(x,y)\in R\implies \#(x)=\#(y)\implies (y,x)\in R\;\forall\;(x,y)\in P(A)$....